# Fama Macbeth regression results

Tags: asset-pricing

I am doing the Fama Macbeth regression analysis for finding the relation between Idiosyncratic volatility and Expected stock return. Stock return is dependent variable and independent variables are: idiovol, beta, size, bm, strev, illiq, max, coskew and idioskew. I have run different models and I get the following results:

1. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (neg insig)
2. Intercept (sig) + idiovol (neg insig) + beta (insig)
3. Intercept (sig) + idiovol (neg sig) + size (sig)
4. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (neg insig) + bm (insig)
5. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (neg insig) + strev (sig)
6. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (neg insig) + illiq (sig)
7. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (pos insig) + max (insig)
8. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (neg insig) + coskew (insig)
9. Intercept (insig) + idiovol (neg insig) + idioskew (sig)
10. Intercept (sig) + idiovol (neg sig) +  beta (insig) + size (sig) + bm (insig) + strev (sig) + illiq (sig at 10%) + max (insig) + coskew (insig) + idioskew (insig)

A)  In the first model idiovol is negative but not significant.  In second model when I include beta again both are insignificant. How I interpret this?
B)   In model third when I include size, idiovol become significant and negative and  size is also significant. It mean that earlier (model 1) idiovol was significantly associated with size and reflects the effect of size in addition to its own effect (plus some other unobservables) that is why idiovol was insignificant earlier but now it showing its true impact on stock returns. Am I correct, I read this from some previous post on the forum.
C)  Now how I interpret the others model and last model in which I have included all the variables.

Please help me in interpreting these results.

Thank you
Regards